# How to combine non-adjacent groups without using branch resets or capturing inside lookarounds?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, pcregrep

Suppose I have the following text:

```markdown
# Should match

- [ ] Some task
- [ ] Some task | [[link]]
- [ ] Some task ^abcdef
- [ ] Some task | [[link]] ^abcdef
- [ ] ! Some task
- [ ] ! Some task | [[link]]
- [ ] ! Some task ^abcdef
- [ ] ! Some task | [[link]] ^abcdef
- [ ] Task one | [ ] ! Task two | [ ] Task three ^abcdef

|     Tracker | Task                    | Backlog  |
| ----------: | :---------------------- | :------- |
| 00:00-00:00 | [ ] Task item           | [[linK]] |
| 00:00-00:00 | [ ] Task item ^abcdef   | [[link]] |
| 00:00-00:00 | [ ] [[task-item]]       | [[link]] |
| 00:00-00:00 | [ ] ! Task item         | [[linK]] |
| 00:00-00:00 | [ ] ! Task item ^abcdef | [[link]] |
| 00:00-00:00 | [ ] ! [[task-item]]     | [[link]] |

# Should not match

- [ ] 
- [ ]
- [ ]  
- [ ] ! 
- [ ] !
- [ ] !  

|     Tracker | Task                    | Backlog  |
| ----------: | :---------------------- | :------- |
| 00:00-00:00 | [ ]                     | [[linK]] |
| 00:00-00:00 | [ ] !                   | [[linK]] |
```

I am interested in several capture groups as follows:

- group `$1`:

  - match: `[` and `]`
- group `$2`:

  - match: any single character (e.g., `\s`) between `[` and `]`
- group `$3`:

  - match: `!`, `?`, or `*` that follows after `[ ]`
- group `$4`:

  - match: task text after `[ ]` without modifier present
- group `$5`:

  - match: task text after `[ ] !` with modifier present

I came up with the following `regex` (i.e., [see demo here](https://regex101.com/r/LVVrrS/20)):

```regex
(?<= \s )
  # Match opening braket (i.e., `[`).
  ( \[ )

  # Match any single character (e.g., `x`).
  ( . )

  # Matching closing braket (i.e., `]`)
  ( \] )
(?= \s* [?!*]? \s* )

# Exclude entries without text (i.e., incl. in tables).
(?! 
  \s* [?!*]? \s* \|
  |
  \s* [?!*]? \s* $
)

# Match the text (i.e., capture based on modifier presence).
(?:
  # Match modifier (i.e., `!`, `?`, or `*`) and the text that follows.
  \s* ( [!?*] ) \s* ( .*? )
  |
  # Match the text that does not follow a modifier.
  \s* (?! [!?*]) \s* ( .*? )
)
# Match until either of the stops that follow are met.
(?= \s+ \^[a-z0-9]{6,} | \s+ \| | \s*$)
```

Which seems to work (i.e., see the picture below), with one exception. The `[` and `]` notation brackets are captured in separate groups (i.e., `[` in the group `$1` and `]` in the group `$3`). How can I capture `[` and `]` as part of the same group (i.e., `$1`)?

[image: demo for regex mentioned]

I am using this `regex` for a TextMate grammar in `VS Code` and [according to the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#textmate-grammars) the expression needs to be a valid Oniguruma regular expression. Based on some attempts, I noticed that the following are not supported:

- branch resets (i.e., `\K`)
- capturing inside lookarounds
- named capture groups

---

#### Edit

[The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird) indicated in the comments that with the `/J` flag enabled the `regex` below works (i.e., [see demo](https://regex101.com/r/0HQc4t/2)):

```regex
(?<= \s )
  # Match opening braket (i.e., `[`).
  (?<g1> \[)

  # Match any single character (e.g., `x`).
  (?<g2> .)

  # Matching closing braket (i.e., `]`)
  (?<g1> \])
(?= \s* [?!*]? \s* )

# Exclude entries without text (i.e., incl. in tables).
(?! 
  \s* [?!*]? \s* \|
  |
  \s* [?!*]? \s* $
)

# Match the text (i.e., capture based on modifier presence).
(?:
  # Match modifier (i.e., `!`, `?`, or `*`) and the text that follows.
  \s* (?<g3>[!?*]) \s* (?<g4>.*?)
  |
  # Match the text that does not follow a modifier.
  \s* (?! [!?*]) \s* (?<g5>.*?)
)
# Match until either of the stops that follow are met.
(?= \s+ \^[a-z0-9]{6,} | \s+ \| | \s*$)
```

It does. However, as I just discovered, it seems that I cannot use named capture groups for `TextMate` grammars and, therefore, I need a different solution.

Comment: You can use the `J` flag and then use the same group name. See https://regex101.com/r/0HQc4t/1 Note that you can omit `{1}`

Comment: @Thefourthbird, that is amazing! I am trying the `J` flag right now to see if it works in `VS Code`.  Oh, thanks for indicating that I can omit `{1}`.

Comment: @MikeM, I need it for syntax highlighting (e.g., https://imgur.com/a/3SEXkqL).

Comment: @MikeM https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oniguruma

Comment: @Thefourthbird, sadly I cannot get the flag `/J` to work in `VS Code`. Also, even something as simple as this (i.e., `(?<name>task)`) fails. I thought named capture groups are supported in Oniguruma... I will try some more, but I guess my best bet is still to figure out a way to adjust the expression.

Comment: Instead of asking a new question, I will adjust this one to drop the named groups and fit my scenario better. Despite this, I am thankful you mentioned the `/J` flag.